# Does removing bucket also removes its object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I saw that `AmazonS3` has `deleteBucket` function, but can't seem to understand if it will automatically remove it's object as well or I need to do the following:

```
List<S3ObjectSummary> objList= S3S.listObjects(bucketName).getObjectSummaries();
        for(S3ObjectSummary objList){
            S3S.deleteObject(bucketName , object.getKey());
        }
        S3S.deleteBucket(bucketName);
```

Comment: You could easily try this on a test bucket, but no, it won't delete the contents.

Comment: A non-empty bucket won't get deleted. You need to delete the contents first.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete objects manually
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a quick way to clean up an S3 Bucket ...

The [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/powershell/) provide a way to delete all of a bucket's contents, along with the S3 Bucket itself. The `Remove-S3Bucket` command has a `-DeleteBucketContent` switch parameter, which will take care of this for you.

```
Remove-S3Bucket -BucketName awstrevor -DeleteBucketContent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a bucket that contains objects using the AWS CLI only if the bucket does not have versioning enabled. If your bucket does not have versioning enabled, you can use the rb (remove bucket) AWS CLI command with --force parameter to remove a non-empty bucket. This command deletes all objects first and then deletes the bucket.

```
aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html#delete-bucket-awscli